# MVC5 textbox showing incorrect data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the admin section of my MVC5 web I have a page which lists all the users in a table, which looks like this:

[image: Users table]

Clicking on `change username` shows a simple page to change the username as follows:

[image: Change username page]

After changing the username (& clicking change username) the page listing all the users is then shown.

> If I now try to change the username for **another** user the username for the previous user (ie the **new** username) is shown on the `change username` page. If I refresh the page the correct username is shown

**For example:**

If I changed user `kevin` to `dave` and then click `change username` for `rikesh` the change username page dispays `dave` instead of `rikesh`.

> If I now refresh the page `rikesh` is shown

**Code:**

```
    public ActionResult ChangeUsername(int userId)
    {
        // get the current username

        var viewModel = new ChangeUserNameViewModel
        {
            UserId = userId,
            UserName = username
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserName", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id="ChangeUserNameForm" }))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = "width: 300px" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="ChangeUserName" name="action:ChangeUserName" id="ChangeUserNameButton" onclick="checkUserNameDifferent()" style="margin-top: 25px; background-color: red">Change Username</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Cancel" name="action:Cancel" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 15px; width: 100px">Cancel</button>
}
```

I thought this might be a caching issue but I get the same problem if I try this in Chrome Incognito mode and also tried to stopping caching on the controller action by annotating it with:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

Comment: Could you show us some code please? In particular it would be useful to see the controller action that is called by `change username` link and what parameters does it get.

Comment: I've updated my post - I missed an important bit of information: If I refresh the page the correct username is shown in the textbox

Comment: try using `ModelState.Clear()`

Comment: @VinylWarmth Can you share the View and how you display changeusername page ?

Comment: Is your POST method redirecting back again to the GET method that generates the first view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it is.....

Comment: And are you absolutely sure that you actually passing the correct `userId` to the `ChangeUsername()` method?

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure the correct id is being passed to `ChangeUserName()`. Why did you ask about redirecting?

Comment: @VinylWarmth How you load this form .. in new page or as partialview in samepage

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you were not just doing something strange :) If you have added `[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]` to the `ChangeUsername` method, then the code should work fine (I cannot reproduce the issue) so there is something else you have not shown us that's causing the issue.

Comment: @AhmedRagheb No partials used for this page

Comment: @VinylWarmth I am thinking of two scenarios, (1- you are passing wrong id, 2- you are using EF and there is a problem that it cache old data try `Context.someTable.AsNoTracking()`

Comment: @AhmedRagheb 1. I am definitely passing the correct id 2. I am using EF - I just tried `Context.User.AsNoTracking()` just before returning in the GET action but still gettting the same problem

Comment: @VinylWarmth Did you debug the code and see that EF return right data using the right id ?! and now you are sure that it is a textbox problem ??!

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you're using `@Html.TextboxFor`.  Try adding `ModelState.Clear()` to the action in your controller.

```
public ActionResult ChangeUsername(int userId)
{
    // Clear any old model state info
    ModelState.Clear();

    // get the current username
    var viewModel = new ChangeUserNameViewModel
    {
        UserId = userId,
        UserName = username
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: I have added `ModelState.Clear()` as you suggested but I am still getting the same problem?

Comment: @VinylWarmth - where are you doing a `ModelState.Clear();` in that code?

Comment: @Developer I am doing it at the start of the action

Comment: @VinylWarmth, `ModelState` has got nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
public ActionResult ChangeUsername(int userId)
{
    // get the current username

    var viewModel = new ChangeUserNameViewModel
    {
        UserId = userId,
        UserName = username
    };
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: `ModelState.Clear();` has nothing to do with the issue (there is no parameter for `UserName` so there is no `ModelState` value for `UserName`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - the object he POSTs for changing the user name has `UserName` proerty with the newly entered name, right? Would that be getting persisted? Cant figure out anything else where that code could go wrong!

Comment: @Developer, Its not a POST method - its a GET method and it has one parameter for `userId` so the only value that is added to `ModelState` is `userId` (and there is no point clearing that anyway). As I noted in the question, I cannot reproduce what OP is claiming.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I'm wondering, then how the old username stays and change only after refresh.

Comment: @Nitin, I have no idea, but its not a result of the code OP has shown us. It suggests a cache issue, but OP has claimed they have added the `OutputCacheAttribute` to prevent that

Comment: May be he missed to show us some code which might contains the issue.